# Is it possible to run Content Scripts from a Chrome extension on the view-source page?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am working on a Chrome extension which runs some content scripts and modifies the HTML / CSS of viewed pages. Is it possible for the extension to access view-source URLs like "view-source:https://stackoverflow.com/" and modify their source? An example scenario is I want the font on every view-source page I open to be 20 pts and blue. There is no mention of this behavior on the [match patterns](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns) documentation page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you won't be able to inject a content script on the view source page in chrome.  An match pattern will match only a small set of valid schemes.  Specifically,  `http://`, `https://`, `file://`, or `ftp://`.

> A match pattern is essentially a URL that begins with a permitted
>   scheme (http, https, file, or ftp, and that can contain '*'
>   characters. The special pattern  matches any URL that starts
>   with a permitted scheme.

Further on, the matches page specifies the exact list of values avaliable in the 'basic syntax' section.

```
<scheme> := '*' | 'http' | 'https' | 'file' | 'ftp'
```

So, ultimately, you won't be able to modify the view-source pages.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought after going through the documentation but it's always nice to get some confirmation.