# How can I change the view-source in Chrome Browser into Dark Mode automatically?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser

When I type "view source" in Chrome Browser, the background is white and the text too small.
So I made this bookmarklet and it works fine. It turns the source code of any HTML,CSS,JS page into a dark mode. Just try in in your bookmarks :

javascript:

```
document.querySelector('meta[name="color scheme"]').setAttribute("content", "dark");
if (document.querySelectorAll('pre').length > 0 {
    document.getElementsByTagName("pre")[0].style.fontSize = "18px";
}
if (document.querySelectorAll('table').length > 0) {
    document.querySelector('table').setAttribute("style", "font-size:18px");
}
```

If you look at a HTML source code into Chrome with the inspector, you will see the HTML code of the view source page. Change the meta tag  `<meta name="color-scheme" content="light dark">` into `<meta name="color-scheme" content="dark">` and it turns the page into a nice Dark mode!!

Now I want to make a Chrome Browser extension to do it automatically.
It works partially with the CSS and JS source code, but not with the HTML pages because their URL starts with "view-source" instead of "https" I guess. So my bookmarklet do it but not my Chrome Browser extension.

manifest.json script :

```
{
    "short_name": "Dark",
    "name": "Medium Dark Mode",

    "background": {
        "scripts": ["darkmode.js"],
        "persistent": false
    },

    "icons": {
        "48": "icon.png"  
    },

    "permissions": [
        "activeTab",
        "tabs"
    ],

    "manifest_version": 2,

    "browser_action": {
        "default_title": "Dark Mode"
    },

    "version": "1.0"
}
```

darmode.js script:

```
document.querySelector('meta[name="color-scheme"]').setAttribute("content", "dark");

if (document.querySelectorAll('pre').length > 0) {
    document.getElementsByTagName("pre")[0].style.fontSize = "18px";
}

if (document.querySelectorAll('table').length > 0) {
    document.querySelector('table').setAttribute("style", "font-size:18px");
}
```

It doesn't work :(

Comment: for the dark theme - try going to `chrome://flags/#enable-force-dark`  and set it to `Enable`. Regardless, still researching about the concept of affecting the view-source with an extension

Comment: [welp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59219381/is-it-possible-to-run-content-scripts-from-a-chrome-extension-on-the-view-source)

Answer (score 0):

### Here's a workaround

You can't do it automatically, but you can add a link (bookmark) to your favourites bar like this:

[image]

And in the link, use your querySelector line, just prefix it with **javascript:**

```
javascript: document.querySelector('meta[name="color-scheme"]').setAttribute("content", "dark");
```

This way, you'll still have to click it after each page refresh, but it's just one click, not so painful - also, you can automatize it if you have a tool like KeyManager. Again, I know this is not *a solution*, and certainly not *THE solution*, but this is the best I was able to hack together, to save my eyes from the white background.